# Can't register users in Firebase ERROR Invariant Violation: `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument., js engine: hermes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to build an app created with React Native and I have I use `@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.5.0",  "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^17.5.0",  "@ react-native-firebase/firestore": "^17.5.0",`

I run the App with `npx react-native run-ios`

My ignorance prevents me from going ahead with the project, stalled after several days since I am trying to register users in Firebase with the logic that I show below, an `auth.js` file where the authentication is and `firebase.js` which has the logic of firebase. It is impossible for me.

I have changed the configuration of these files several times, and I cannot add here all the times I have made changes, but there have been several.

However I can't get it to register a new user.

**I EDIT THE QUESTION**
I EDIT THE QUESTION

I have added the Podfile at the suggestion of a colleague.
I must also say that I have followed the instructions for [React Native Firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/), but if I make all the changes suggested in AppDelegate.m and in Podfile, the project breaks and won't start again from the terminal nor from Xcode either.

The error refers to the following file:

```
/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/EventEmitter/NativeEventEmitter.js
```

The app is still working, the errors have changed, but the one I'm logging now is the following:

```
 LOG  Running "Cositas enter code here" with {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument., js engine: hermes
 at ?anon_0_ (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.ApuntesDelCampo:132800:100)
    at next (native)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.ApuntesDelCampo:20867:26)
    at _next (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.ApuntesDelCampo:20886:29)
    at anonymous (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.ApuntesDelCampo:20891:14)
    at tryCallTwo (/Users/distiller/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:61:9)
    at doResolve (/Users/distiller/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:216:25)
    at Promise (/Users/distiller/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:82:14)
    at anonymous (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.ApuntesDelCampo:20883:25)
    at apply (native)
```

I understand that the causes can be several, that's why I'm here, since I can't find the way to do it after many tries and many changes that I made suggested by other similar problems found on Stackoverflow. Maybe someone will see the error that I have in the code or can suggest a correct configuration.

I don't understand if the iOS configuration may be affecting it, whenever I run the `"pod install"` all the dependencies are installed again and it shows the :

```
[!] The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries:

    The Swift pod `FirebaseCoreInternal` depends upon `GoogleUtilities`, which does not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.
```

I show the files and I hope you can give me some idea to be able to correct this and move on,

**============ Podfile =======**

````
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'ApuntesDelCampo' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'ApuntesDelCampoTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
````

**========. RegisterScreen.js  ==================**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { registerUser } from '../../services/auth'

import styles from './AuthStyles/RegisterScreenStyles'

const RegisterScreen = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');

  const handleRegister = async () => {
    if (email && password && username) {
      const { success, error } = await registerUser(email, password, username);

      if (success) {
        // Registro exitoso
        Alert.alert('Registro exitoso', '¡Usuario registrado correctamente!');
      } else {
        // Error en el registro
        Alert.alert('Error de registro', error);
      }
    } else {
      // Validación de campos vacíos
      Alert.alert('Campos vacíos', 'Por favor, completa todos los campos.');
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Registro</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Nombre de usuario"
        value={username}
        onChangeText={ setUsername}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Correo electrónico"
        value={email}
        onChangeText={setEmail}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Contraseña"
        secureTextEntry
        value={password}
        onChangeText={setPassword}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={handleRegister}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Registrarse</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}

export default RegisterScreen;
```

**===========. auth.js. =============**

```
import { firebaseFirestore, firebaseAuth } from "./firebase";


// Registro de usuario
export const registerUser = async (email, password, username) => {
  try {
    const { user } = await firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    // Almacenar el nombre de usuario en Firestore
    await firebaseFirestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
      username,
    });

    return { success: true, user };
  } catch (error) {
    return { success: false, error: error.message };
  }
};
```

**========. firebase.js. ========**

```
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app'
import '@react-native-firebase/firestore'
import '@react-native-firebase/auth'

// Configura Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxx",
  projectId: "cxxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
  appId: "xxxxxx"
};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
}

const firebaseFirestore = firebase.firestore();
const firebaseAuth = firebase.auth();

export { firebaseFirestore, firebaseAuth }
```

Comment: Can you add your `Podfile` as well? And this only happens on iOS right?

Comment: Of course, I already edited the question @user16967562

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're running `pod install` without static library, it is throwing an error and not actually installing Firebase.

Disable flipper since flipper doesn't work with static lib:

```
# Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work if enabled
# :flipper_configuration => flipper_config, <-- comment this line
# An absolute path to your application root
```

Inside the `target 'ApuntesDelCampo' do` add two following just above `flags = ...`:

```
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static

$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

# Flags change depending on the env values.
flags = get_default_flags()
```

And also make sure you have added `GoogleService-Info.plist` to your project.

Now run `pod install` again, and try installing the App.

Comment: hello. I have followed your instructions and so far I have no errors. But it does not register the user, the application shows a banner that I show in the screenshot, the console does not show errors either. No Firebase App '['DEFAULT']' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp(). I have looked for solutions and maybe modifying AppDelegate.m , as also explained in the instructions of rnfirebase.io, (#import <Firebase.h> //// and also adding : [FIRApp configure];) What do you think would be better? for this error? Thank you https://ibb.co/7p1Ts24

Comment: making the changes that I have suggested @user16967562  , if the user is registered, but the user is not saved in a collection, I think I should modify the code to save the user in firestore or Realtime. Again more problems.

Comment: There is no need to call `firebase.initializeApp()`, you can just put `GoogleService-Info.plist` and link it to the target in xCode like shown in the [docs](https://rnfirebase.io/#generating-ios-credentials).

Comment: thank you. that is over, but it still does not register the user: `Error Object is not a function`

Comment: Where does that exactly happen? If it does happen when creating a user then replace the import with `import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth` and call it like so `auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).`

Comment: Thanks again. I have already corrected this problem, now another one has arisen. I can't log in. But what this question was looking for, I solved it following your advice, so your answer will be good. Now I will try to correct the login problems