# ERROR Invariant Violation: `new NativeEventEmitter()` when trying to use firebase with react-native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am encountering an error with the following message:

ERROR: Invariant Violation: new NativeEventEmitter() requires a non-null argument.
at Home (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.MuscleSync:187879:26)
at StaticContainer (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.MuscleSync:158191:17)

I am using Xcode version 14.3.1 (14E300c) on a Mac with the M1 chip, and I am testing on an iOS 14 simulator.

I have already tried various troubleshooting steps, including cleaning the project, reinstalling dependencies, and checking the Firebase configuration. However, the issue persists.

The error message suggests that `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument. It seems that there might be an issue with the configuration or initialization of Firebase or the `auth` module.

Here is the relevant code from my project:

1. Podfile:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'  # CocoaPodsのデフォルトのソースリポジトリを追加

target 'AppName' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for AppName
  platform :ios, '13.0'
  
  # Uncomment the following lines if needed
  # pod 'Firebase/CoreOnly'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  # pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  # pod 'Firebase/Auth', '10.11.0'
  
  pod 'RNFBApp', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app', :version => '> 18.1.0'
  pod 'RNFBAuth', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth', :version => '> 18.1.0'
 
  # Add the following lines if needed
  # pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  # Disable flipper since flipper doesn't work with static lib
  # Comment out the flipper_configuration line
  # An absolute path to your application root
  # use_flipper! :post_install

  # Add the following lines for static library
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  target 'AppNameTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

2. `GoogleService-Info.plist`
   The GoogleService-Info.plist file is located at AppName/ios/AppName/GoogleService-Info.plist.
3. `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
   "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^18.1.0",
   "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.1.0",
   "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^18.1.0",
   "react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0",
   "react": "^18.2.0",
   "react-native": "^0.72.0",
   ...
 },
```

4. Source code: src/firebaseAuth.ts
   `src/firebaseAuth.ts`

```
import Config from 'react-native-config'
import { appInfo } from '@@/const/appInfo'
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app'
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: Config.API_KEY || '',
  authDomain: Config.AUTH_DOMAIN || '',
  databaseURL: Config.DATABASE_URL || '', 
  projectId: Config.PROJECT_ID || '',
  storageBucket: Config.STORAGE_BUCKET || '',
  messagingSenderId: Config.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID || '',
  appId: Config.APP_ID || '',
  measurementId: Config.MEASUREMENT_ID || '',
}

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, appInfo.name)
} else {
  firebase.app(appInfo.name)
}

export const isLogin = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const unsubscribe = auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      unsubscribe() // Unsubscribe after the first invocation

      if (user) {
        // User is signed in
        console.log('User is signed in')
        resolve(user)
      } else {
        // User is signed out
        console.log('User is signed out')
        resolve(null)
      }
    })
  })
}
```

The problem occurs when I try to use Firebase or the auth module. I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions to resolve this issue and properly utilize Firebase without encountering this error.

I have also tried running the following commands multiple times as part of my troubleshooting process:

`watchman watch-del-all && lsof -n -P -i :8081 -t | xargs kill && rm -rf ios/build && rm -rf android/app/build && rm -rf node_modules && yarn install && rm -rf ~ /Library/Caches/CocoaPods && rm -rf Pods && rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData && cd ios && pod deintegrate && pod setup && bundle exec pod install && cd .. && ./node_modules/react-native /scripts/packager.sh --reset-cache`

Thank you for your assistance in resolving this issue.

Please let me know if you need any additional information or code snippets.

Comment: It seems to be the same problem as

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76404603/cant-register-users-in-firebase-error-invariant-violation-new-nativeeventemit

but it does not solve